# recursive function in sas for a fibonacci numbers

Tags: sas

I´m trying to define a recursive function in SAS, as follows

```
%macro f(n);
%if &n<=1 %then %put f(&n)=&n;
%else %put f(&n)=%eval(f(%eval(&n-1))+f(%eval(&n-2)));
%mend;
```

but when `i>=2` doesn´t work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Macros aren't really built for this type of functionality. I would recommend looking into PROC FCMP instead. Here's a paper about 10 years old that implements the Fibonacci formula using PROC FCMP https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/024-2010.pdf

Comment: Your macro is NOT calling itself, so it is not recursive.  It does NOT return a result, it just prints something to the log, so you cannot make it recursive without changing how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive macro is highly atypical.  You will have a much better recursive programming experience using `Proc DS2` and implementing methods therein.

Regardless,  you must understand that macro is not a normal functional programming language; it is a source code generator with side-effects.  Your macro might not emit any source code and be programmed solely for side effects, or it might be written to emit source code according to a template and have no other side effects.

```
%macro fib(n);

  %if &n < 0 %then %abort cancel;

  %if &n = 0 %then 
    0 /* emit source code 0. The %if is a recursion sentinel */
  ;
  %else 
  %if &n = 1 %then 
    1 /* emit source code 1. The %if is a recursion sentinel */
  ;
  %else %do;
    /* emit source code that is side effect of eval summing recursive invocation */
    %eval (
      %fib(%eval(&n-1)) + %fib(%eval(&n-2))
    )
  %end;

%mend;

%put %fib(0);
%put %fib(1);
%put %fib(2);
%put %fib(3);
%put %fib(4);
%put %fib(5);
%put %fib(6);
```

The net result emitted is from macro facility (sub-system).

%fib(6) code generation would be

```
%put
    %eval (    
      %eval ( /* 5 */
        %eval ( /* 4 */
          %eval ( /* 3 */
            %eval ( /* 2 */
              1 /* 1 */
              +
              0 /* 1 */
            )
            +
            %eval ( /* 1 */
              1
            )
          )
          +
          %eval ( /* 2 */
            1 /* 1 */
            +
            0 /* 1 */
          )
        )
        +
        %eval ( /* 3 */
          %eval ( /* 2 */
            1 /* 1 */
            +
            0 /* 1 */
          )
          +
          %eval ( /* 1 */
            1
          )
        )
      )
      +
      %eval ( /* 4 */
        %eval ( /* 3 */
          %eval ( /* 2 */
            1 /* 1 */
            +
            0 /* 1 */
          )
          +
          %eval ( /* 1 */
            1
          )
        )
        +
        %eval ( /* 2 */
          1 /* 1 */
          +
          0 /* 1 */
        )
      )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%macro f(n);
%if &n<=2 %then 1;
%else  %eval(%f(%eval(&n-1))+%f(%eval(&n-2)));
%mend;
```